# How can I show that a specific object is cofibrant in $s\mathbf{Alg}_{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

**Set-up:**

I will use the notation $\underline{S}$ to denote the constant simplicial commutative ring which is $S$ in all degrees and has face and degeneracy maps the identity.

Let $R_{\bullet}$ be a simplicial commutative ring. We may think of $R_{\bullet}$ as a simplicial commutative $\textbf{Z}[x]$-algebra by choosing an element $f\in\pi_{0}R_{\bullet}$ and constructing the map $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}\to R_{\bullet}$ which in degree $n$ sends $x$ to the degenerate image of $f$ in $R_{n}$.

Given such an $f\in\pi_{0}R_{\bullet}$, we have the multiplicatively closed subset $W=\{1,f,f^{2},\ldots\}\subseteq\pi_{0}R_{\bullet}$. We can define the localization of $R_{\bullet}$ at $f$ by
$$
R_{\bullet}[1/f]:=R_{\bullet}\otimes_{\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}}^{\textbf{L}}\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}.
$$

Computing a derived tensor product $-\otimes^{\textbf{L}}T_{\bullet}$ means finding a cofibrant replacement $T_{\bullet}^{c}$ of $T_{\bullet}$ and computing $-\otimes T_{\bullet}^{c}$. In any model category, an object $X$ is cofibrant if the unique map $\emptyset\to X$ is a cofibration, where $\emptyset$ is the initial object, and a cofibrant replacement of $T_{\bullet}$ is a cofibrant object $T_{\bullet}^{c}$ that is weakly equivalent to $T_{\bullet}$.

In the same manner that localization of rings is flat, I expect that localization of simplicial commutative rings should satisfy
$$
R_{\bullet}\otimes_{\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}}^{\textbf{L}}\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}\cong R_{\bullet}\otimes_{\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}}\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)};
$$
that is, $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y](xy-1)}$ is cofibrant, and thus can be taken as its own cofibrant replacement. Also, this should be true for the reason that localization $R_{\bullet}[1/f]$ can also be defined as localization at each degree; i.e., $R_{\bullet}[1/f]:=\left(R_{n}[1/f]\right)_{\bullet}$, writing $f$ for its denegerate image in $R_{n}$. That is what the underived tensor product on the right gives us.

Goerss-Schemmerhorn, in Proposition 4.21 of [Model Categories and Simplicial Methods](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609537.pdf), states that a map in $s\textbf{Alg}_{R}$, the category of simplicial commutative $R$-algebras, is a cofibration if and only if it is a retract of a free morphism. We can define a free morphism in $s\textbf{Alg}_{\textbf{Z}[x]}$ as follows:

Let $\Delta$ be the simplex category with objects $[n]=\{0,\ldots n\}$ and arrows order preserving functions. Let $\Delta_{+}\subseteq\Delta$ be the subcategory with the same objects and arrows only surjective morphisms. Let $R_{\bullet}:\Delta^{op}\to\textbf{Alg}$ be a simplicial algebra. We say $R_{\bullet}$ is $s$-free if the induced object
$$
R_{\bullet,+}:\Delta_{+}^{op}\to\textbf{Alg}
$$
is free. We say that a map $R_{\bullet}\to S_{\bullet}$ in $s\textbf{Alg}_{\textbf{Z}[x]}$ is $s$-free if $R_{\bullet,+}\to S_{\bullet,+}$ is isomorphic to the inclusion $R_{\bullet,+}\hookrightarrow R_{\bullet,+}\sqcup S'$ where $S'$ is $s$-free. Finally, a map $R_{\bullet}\to S_{\bullet}$ is free if it is $s$-free on a set of objects $\{\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}(P_{k})\}$, where each $P_{k}$ is a projective $\textbf{Z}[x]$-module and $\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet}-$ is the symmetric algebra functor.

---

**Question:**

I want to show that $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}$ is a cofibrant object in $s\textbf{Alg}_{\textbf{Z}[x]}$.

By definition, that means we must show that $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}\to\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}$ is a cofibration, since $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}$ is the initial object in $s\textbf{Alg}_{\textbf{Z}[x]}$.

By Goerss-Schemmerhorn, we must show that $\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}\to\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}$ is a retract of a free morphism. That is, we must show that there exists a free morphism $g:A_{\bullet}\to B_{\bullet}$ such that the following diagram commutes, and the horizontal rows compose to give the respective identity maps.

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}&\ra{}&A_{\bullet}&\ra{}&\underline{\textbf{Z}[x]}\\
\da{}&&\da{g}&&\da{}\\
\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}&\ra{}&B_{\bullet}&\ra{}&\underline{\textbf{Z}[x,y]/(xy-1)}
\end{array}
$$

But I am stuck on how to check this condition. For example, what should $g$ be? Any hints are appreciated, or if there's a better approach!

Comment: You're not trying to show that $\mathbf Z[x]\stackrel{a}{\to}\mathbf Z[x,x^{-1}]$ is a retraction as a morphism, you're trying to show that it's a retraction as an object of the category of arrows, namely of some free arrow $b:\mathbf Z[x]\to B$. This involves a section of a ring map $B\to \mathbf Z[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, I'm afraid I don't follow. Are you saying that the initial object in $s\mathbf{Alg}_{\underline{\mathbf{Z}[x]}}$ is a map of arrows $b\to a$? What is an "arrow" or a "free arrow" here, and how is it a simplicial $\mathbf{Z}[x]$-algebra? What is $B$? Do you have a place to point me where I can learn more, or can you flesh out your comment more completely?

Comment: Every cofibration is a retract *of a free morphism.* This statement does not mean that every cofibration is a retraction. I would suggest a general reference on model categories, such as Hovey.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, I'm aware of that characterization and mention it in my post. I know the definition of a free morphism but tabled it for this specific question because it wasn't the specific problem I had at the time. Is my confusion therefore that "retract"$\neq$"retraction"? Because I fail to see how "every cofibration is a retract of a free morphism" doesn't mean "every cofibration is a retraction," unless the concepts are different. If so, what yucky terminology!

Comment: They are different, but it’s not really a homonym issue. A retraction is a split epimorphism. An object $x$ of a category is a retract of $y$ if there exists a retraction $y\to x$. When we ask that a cofibration be a retract of a free arrow, we are viewing both arrows *as objects of the arrow category.* Note that there is no way to interpret the modifying phrase “of a free arrow” if “retract” is supposed to be a synonym of “retraction.”

Comment: @KevinCarlson, thank you! I was interpreting “of a free arrow” to mean that the section was a free morphism, but I believe my confusion here is cleared up (not to say I won’t run into many more confusions in the future!). I will edit the post accordingly soon. Thank you again!

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad that helped.

Comment: I haven't thought about what $A\to B$ should be ; but perhaps an easier approach to show the desired equality would be to use the fact that direct limits are exact and commute with tensor product. In this setting, exact will mean that they preserve weak equivalences, so "are their own derived functor".  So $(R \otimes^L-) \circ \varinjlim = (R \otimes^L-)  \circ L\varinjlim = L((R\otimes -) \circ \varinjlim) = L(\varinjlim\circ (R\otimes -)) = L\varinjlim \circ (R\otimes^L -) = \varinjlim R\otimes^L-$. Now note that $\mathbf Z [x,x^{-1}]$ is a direct limit of modules $\cong \mathbf Z[x]$